# scikit python - SVR regression: predicting multiple points results in the same repeating output

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, svm, prediction

I'm trying to train and predict with an SVM as follows:

```
for i in range(numStocks):
    y_p = []
    X, y, X_p, scaler, stockUsed = randomStockData(stockList)
    clf = svm.SVR(kernel='rbf', C=1, gamma=0.1)
    clf.fit(X, y)
    reshapedX_p = X_p.reshape(1,-1)
    for j in range(5):
        y_p.append(clf.predict(reshapedX_p))
        reshapedX_p = np.append(reshapedX_p[0][1:],y_p[-1])
        reshapedX_p = reshapedX_p.reshape(1, reshapedX_p.shape[0])
    y_p = [x*scaler for x in y_p]
    rescaledX_p = [x*scaler for x in X_p]
    print(y_p)
    plt.plot(rescaledX_p, label='closep test')
    plt.plot(range(len(rescaledX_p),len(rescaledX_p)+len(y_p)), y_p, label='predicted')
    plt.legend(loc='lower left', shadow=True)
    pylab.savefig(homePath+'predictResults/'+stockUsed+'.png', facecolor='#ffffff', edgecolor='#ffffff')
    plt.close()
```

But plots all come out like this:
[image]
[image]

Looking at the last few "prediction input" (reshapedX_p) at each iteration, with y_p as well:

`print(reshapedX_p[0][-5:], y_p)` inside the inner for loop

```
(array([ 0.00458431,  0.00465051,  0.00470016,  0.00466706,  0.00462568]), [])
(array([ 0.00465051,  0.00470016,  0.00466706,  0.00462568,  0.00415898]), [array([ 0.00415898])])
(array([ 0.00470016,  0.00466706,  0.00462568,  0.00415898,  0.00415898]), [array([ 0.00415898]), array([ 0.00415898])])
(array([ 0.00466706,  0.00462568,  0.00415898,  0.00415898,  0.00415898]), [array([ 0.00415898]), array([ 0.00415898]), array([ 0.00415898])])
(array([ 0.00462568,  0.00415898,  0.00415898,  0.00415898,  0.00415898]), [array([ 0.00415898]), array([ 0.00415898]), array([ 0.00415898]), array([ 0.00415898])])
```

It's clear that the input to the prediction at each step is in fact changing, but the SVM simply spits out the exact same value as the last step after the first prediction.

Do I need to re-fit the SVM every time as well? I wouldn't think I would have to.

Comment: It looks like you are using nearly the same exact input every single time to your SVM. You are simply shifting your input vector up and appending the last prediction. What is the size of reshapedX_p? The very similar inputs may not change the prediction. You can try `clf.predict(np.random.rand(len(reshapedX_p)))` to see if you are getting different predictions.

Comment: hey thanks for the ideas. i tried the random idea, and confirmed random values would get appended to the end of the graph instead of a flat line. i printed reshapedX_p at each cycle, and each time it was size (1,100). so it is definitely getting passed different vectors with each prediction loop